# How is called such a knob / potentiometer?

Tags: audio, potentiometer

On a Roland TR09 [(rear view)](http://cdm.link/app/uploads/2016/09/tr-09_rear_gal-1024x171.jpg) (Roland's 2016 recreation of their famous TR909):

[image]

we can see a **stereo volume potentiometer**, that is smaller than usual.

Question: Is this

1. a normal potentiometer + a "striated" black cap (if so, what is the proper name? I guess striated cap is not the right name, I haven't found anything with this name)

or

2. some small potentiometer with black rubber-looking shaft, all-in-one?

Note: it's not a sourcing question, but I'd like to know what kind of component it is, and the proper name of it (this will allow me to search then).

Comment: Sometimes they are called "knurled" although typically knurled knobs are a hatch pattern. On Mouser they are referred to as "Knurled - Straight". You would usually source the knob separate from the potentiometer itself, it slides onto the shaft.

Answer (score 3):

Pot. Knobs come in 3 types "Flat" or D shape, Slotted and Knurled 20 or 40 teeth as well as various shaft length , 15 to 35mm in 5mm increments with linear and log. (audio) profiles and shaft diameters such as 6mm.

This would be a *right angle PCB mount, log. , knurled 6mm 40 tooth, Pot.*

Comment: Thanks! Do you think I should look for 2. (pot+knob all in one), or 1. (I should shop pot and knob separately)?

Comment: Something else: when pot manufacturers say "16mm pot" or "9mm pot", does 16 and 9 refer to shaft, width, height, diameter, something else, etc. ?

Comment: approx. diameter

Comment: For example [this one](http://www.retroamplis.com/WebRoot/StoreES2/Shops/62070367/4C93/99E7/7675/88B9/5A47/C0A8/2936/539C/RV16AF_20_15K_B1.jpg) seems to be a 16mm. The shaft cylinder has not a 16mm diameter, right?

Comment: Body diameter, not shaft